# Junit strange behaviour with setup method, elements that have been initialized in setup() method, are not updating in @test method

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have the following Junit test:

```
@Before
    public void setup() {
        origValue = 0.7f;
        optValue = 0.3f;
        NdaElementUtils.setDoubleValue(element, Parameter.getName(), origValue);
        NdaElementUtils.setDoubleValue(element, Parameter.getOptimizedName(), optValue);
    }

    @Test
    public void revertedChangesTest() {
        setConfiguration(0.3, Status.ACTIVE, "[1.0 1.0]");
        objectUnderTest.disable(element, Parameter);
        assertEquals(origValue, NdaElementUtils.getDoubleObjectValue(element, Parameter.getOptimizedName()), 0);
    }
```

I have set the "origValue" and "optValue" in the setup() method, and I check if after run "objectUnderTest.disable(element, Parameter);" the optimazedvalue retrieved from "element" is equal to original value. This must be true, so the method work fine, but the test fail. However if I set the "origValue" and "optValue" in the test:

```
@Before
    public void setup() {
        origValue = 0.7f;
        optValue = 0.3f;
    }

    @Test
    public void revertedChangesTest() {
        setConfiguration(0.3, Status.ACTIVE, "[1.0 1.0]");
        NdaElementUtils.setDoubleValue(element, Parameter.getName(), origValue);
       NdaElementUtils.setDoubleValue(element, Parameter.getOptimizedName(), optValue);
        objectUnderTest.disable(element, Parameter);
        assertEquals(origValue, NdaElementUtils.getDoubleObjectValue(element, Parameter.getOptimizedName()), 0);
    }
```

it passes. 
I do not understand what happens but it must be a logic explanation.
Someone can help me to understand?
I use the same set values of "origValue" and "optValue" in all the tests, so I think it is better to initialize them in setup() method.

Comment: I see at least one difference. You call `setConfiguration(0.3, Ericsson4gCellAmoStatus.ACTIVE, "[1.0 1.0]")` before `NdaElementUtils.setDoubleValue(...)`

Comment: Do you use `@Rule` ?

Comment: What is the value if not `0.7f` ?  Also, can you post the code for `NdaElementUtils.setDoubleValue()` so we can see what is going on in there?

Comment: I have fixed it, thank you for your responses. Logan was right, internally the value was being modified due to the different order of the method, but I debuged but I did not notive this.